Clarification of notions regarding kinetic energy and kinetic theory of matter
To give a background of what I have been taught in school, I am currently in 9th grade. Last year in chemistry, we were taught about the 'kinetic theory of matter', which stated that all matter is in a state of continuous motion and possesses kinetic energy on account of this motion. We were also taught that temperature was the 'average kinetic energy' of an object.
This year in physics, we learned about kinetic energy of a body, which is $KE = \frac{mv^2}{2}$.
Thus, a stationary body has 'no kinetic energy'. Here lies my confusion, regarding the following questions:

If a stationary body has $0$ kinetic energy, why does it still possess non-zero temperature

If velocity plays such a role in the equation of kinetic energy, why can't I physically feel that moving objects are much 'hotter' than stationary ones. For example, in cricket, if a ball is moving fast, why isn't it insanely hot and thus unsafe to catch by a fielder?

Why are these two 'kinetic energies', which possess the same name seemingly so different in concept.



A macroscopic object is in motion when all of its constituent particles (atoms, molecules, etc) have a defined velocity vector $\vec{v}$ in the same direction. When this happens, they all move simultaneously, resulting in the total motion of the macroscopic object.
Microscopically, all of the constituent particles are also in a constant state of motion: bouncing off each other, vibrating, rotating, etc. But each velocity vector of each particle has a random direction and magnitude. Accounting also for the intermolecular bonds that hold matter stable (at least in solids and liquids), the result is that the object does not move through this "internal motion", because the molecules are not all synchronized. If there are no strong intermolecular bonds, as in the case for gases, if set freely all of the molecules will move in random directions and the gas will expand and dissipate. But the center of mass of the system will not move. This explains why stationary objects still have a temperature yet they don't have a macroscopically definable kinetic energy. It's also important to point out that the kinetic energy of the constituent particles is not the only "cause" of a temperature. The important magnitude here is the internal energy, and internal energy accounts both for kinetic and potential energy, the potential energy that is for example stored in intermolecular bonds.
For your second question, the answer has two parts. First, the energy that objects store and can transfer through heat is typically much larger than the  kinetic energy said object would have due to its macroscopic motion. For example, say you heat 1 kg of water by $\Delta T=10 $ K. The energy the water gains is
$$Q = c_p m \Delta T = 4180 \mathrm{\frac{J}{kg\cdot K}}\cdot 1 \ \mathrm{kg}\cdot 10 \ \mathrm{K} = 41800 \ \mathrm{J},$$
because the heat capacity $c_p$ of water is rather high. How fast would the same amount of matter have to move to equate that amount of energy? You can calculate it yourself, and it turns out to be around $\sim 290$ m/s. That's much, much faster than anything you would typically interact with. If the water moved at $1$ m/s, a more usual speed, it would only hold $0.5$ J of kinetic energy, and this amount of energy is simply not enough to heat anything to a significant degree.
The second part of the answer deals with heat transfer. Heat transfers from object to object through conduction, convection or radiation. I won't detail these concepts, but the essential point is that heat transfers in multiple ways, and it's usually a process that takes a certain amount of time. How would you transfer the macroscopic kinetic energy of a body into you, in such a way that it results in heat and not more macroscopic motion? Really, the only way is through an inelastic collision. And in fact, if an object at sufficient speed collides against another, they will both heat up as they change the macroscopic kinetic energy into microscopic kinetic energy. For example, if you shoot a bullet into a steel plate and immediately touch both, they will feel rather hot, as the bullet is moving at a very high speed.

Oh, so it's about considering a body vs its constituents? For example the 'velocity' of a body and a molecule inside it may differ completely in direction, but taking the average of the velocity of all the molecules would give the velocity of the body?

Exactly, if the average velocity is zero (as with a stationary body), the object is not in motion. Notice I say "velocity" and not "speed", since the direction is relevant.

To add, were you to correctly measure all of the positions and velocities of atoms in an object and feed them into a super-duper-computer, you could predict the behavior of the whole system using only the physics definition ($\frac 1 2 m v^2$).  However, measuring those positions and velocities is basically impossible.  The best we can do is replace them with random variables.  The result of doing so leads to the "thermal energy" appearing in one random term, and the "kinetic energy" (as taught in your physics class) appearing in a non-random term, capturing the mean motion of all particles.

For the sake of increased clarity, we can expand the concept of "kinetic energy" to include not just the kinetic energy associated with the body's center of mass motion (call that $T$), but also the kinetic energy associated with the body's parts (call that $U$) - the "internal energy" - writing the total as $H = T + U$. So: think of $H$ as a generalization of the kinetic energy that (a) accounts for the motion of the body's parts and (b) is additive. Recursively speaking, $U$ is the sum of the kinetic energy associated with the body's parts and of their respective internal energies, as a consequence of the additivity requirement.
You could expand the concept yet further by allowing even non-composite bodies to have non-zero internal energy. Then $U$ would become a fundamental attribute in its own right, and not just a bookkeeping device. So, in that way, it can be considered as a form of classical physics that goes beyond "classical" classical physics.
In non-relativistic theory, $T = ½mv^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the body, $$ is the body's center of mass velocity and $v = ||$ (the magnitude of $$) is the body's speed. The revised expression is
$$H = \frac{mv^2}2 + U.$$
In the body's rest frame $H = U$, which can now be non-zero to account for the very issues you're raising. It (meaning $H$) can also be made additive as follows. Suppose you have two bodies with respective data $(m_0, _0, U_0)$ and $(m_1, _1, U_1)$. Then for the combined "body" that is made up of these two bodies as its components, you have:
$$m = m_0 + m_1,\quad  = \frac{m_0 _0 + m_1 _1}{m_0 + m_1},\quad U = U_0 + U_1 + δU,$$
where the extra component $δU$ is the contribution to the "total body's" internal energy arising from the motion of the two component bodies around the combined body's center of mass. Additivity
$$H = H_0 + H_1$$
is achieved by setting
$$δU = \frac{m_0 m_1}{m_0 + m_1} \frac{|_0 - _1|^2}2.$$
The temperature of a stationary body can, in this light, be seen as arising from all the contributions $δU$ to the total body, as well as all the contributions $U_0$ and $U_1$ to the body's parts that ultimately arise from the parts of the parts.
Since you're (now) 13 years past 9th grade, which comes out to 22nd grade or about the time of a Physics PhD (if going on that track), give or take a year, so we can go a bit further with this, here.
A similar exercise could be carried out in Relativity. There, the relativistic version of $T$ is given by:
$$T = \frac{Mv^2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - αv^2}},\quad M = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 - αv^2}}\quad \left(α = \frac1{c^2} > 0\right),$$
with the non-relativistic case arising as the limit of $α → 0$. In this case, additivity falls on the velocity-dependent "moving mass" $M$ (which, in present-day literature is now referred to, instead, as the "total energy" $E = Mc^2$), rather than on the "rest mass" $m$. A similar generalization to
$$H = T + U = \frac{Mv^2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - αv^2}} + U,$$
allows us to achieve additivity, $H = H_0 + H_1$, with an appropriate adjustment $δU$ to $U$, so that two bodies with respective data $(m_0, _0, U_0)$ and $(m_1, _1, U_1)$ combine to form a body with
$$M = M_0 + M_1,\quad  = \frac{M_0 _0 + M_1 _1}{M_0 + M_1},\quad U = U_0 + U_1 + δU,$$
but, also
$$m = m_0 + m_1 + α δU.$$
In Relativity, the extra contribution $δU$ to "internal energy" will also provide a contribution to the "total body"-s rest mass $m$, through the mass-energy equivalence $α δU = δU/c^2$.
The expression for $δU$ is a bit more complicated
$$δU = \frac1α\left(\left(\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1 - α{v_0}^2}} + \frac{m_1}{\sqrt{1 - α{v_1}^2}}\right)\sqrt{1 - αv^2} - m_0 - m_1\right),$$
and I won't even try to work out the algebra on it any further (except maybe in a later edit, time-permitting). But in the limit as $α → 0$, $δU → (m_0m_1)/(m_0 + m_1) × |_0 - _1|^2/2$.
As a side note: you could actually think of the difference between $M$ and $m$, itself, as having arisen from the body's kinetic energy $T$ as follows. Set
$$w = \frac{v^2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - αv^2}} \left(= \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - αv^2}}α\right).$$
In the limit $α → 0$ of non-relativistic theory, $w → ½v^2$.
Then the part of the kinetic energy arising from the rest mass $m$ would be $mw$. The contribution it provides to the mass $M$ is $αmw$. The kinetic energy arising from this extra mass is $(αmw)w$. It's contribution to the mass $M$ is $α(αmw)w$, and so on (to $α((αmw)w)w$, etc); thus leading to the expression:
$$M = m + αmw + α(αmw)w + α(α(αmw)w)w + ⋯ = \frac{m}{1 - αw} = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1 - αv^2}},$$
since
$$1 - αw = \sqrt{1 - αv^2}.$$
In Relativity, even the temperature (and the internal energy associated with it) will increase the body's rest mass! Just a tiny bit, but it still counts. You could think of the rest mass, itself, as comprising an additive velocity-independent part $μ$ plus the contribution $αU$ arising from the body's internal energy $U$, so that $m = μ + αU$. Additivity is then ensured since
$$μ = m - αU = (m_0 + m_1 + αδU) - α(U_0 + U_1 + δU) = (m_0 - αU_0) + (m_1 - αU_1) = μ_0 + μ_1.$$
One way of accounting for the additivity of $μ$, after the fact, is to assume that $μ = 0$ (and $μ_0 = 0$ and $μ_1 = 0$, etc.) and that the rest mass is purely internal energy, $m = αU$ (i.e. that $U = mc^2$). Then, the $U$ in the revised "kinetic energy" expression $H = ½mv^2 + U$, in the non-relativistic case, could be thought of as an attempt to recoup the "rest energy" $mc^2$ of Relativity.
Then, in that case, the statements "internal energy goes up with temperature" and "rest mass goes up with temperature" become two sides of the same coin.

$H=U$!! Ah, that makes sense, the internal energy is still present even in rest frame

"Since you're (now) 13 years past 9th grade, which comes out to 22nd grade or about the time of a Physics PhD " No, I am not 13 years past 9th grade, I am in 9th grade of school, ie freshman year of high school

But the part before you delved into relativity made a lot of sense thank you
